# Direct user message doesn't work with Spring Websocket

Tags: spring-websocket, spring-rabbit, sockjs, spring-messaging, stompjs

I am trying send direct messages to user. Application hasn't done authentication so there is temporary solution for creating websocket session users as you can see in added code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {

        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new CustomHandshakeHandler())
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/", "/exchange/");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    // only for dev purpose
    public static class CustomHandshakeHandler extends DefaultHandshakeHandler {

        @Override
        protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) {
            String username = "user-123";
            return new StompPrincipal(username);
        }

        @Data
        @AllArgsConstructor
        @NoArgsConstructor
        public static class StompPrincipal implements Principal {
            private String name;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my RabbitMQ listener which handle event with message and send direct message to test user `user-123` via websockets:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${event.queue.message-created}")
public void handleMessageCreatedEvent(MessageCreatedEvent event) {
    String devUser = "user-123";
    log.info("MSG received {}.", event); 
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(devUser, "/exchange/amq.direct/chat.message", event);
}
```

Message is handled with rabbit listener and send with simple messaging template, but didn't arrive to frontend client in javascript.

Here is how I am trying to handle these messages:

```
$(function () {
    var stompClient;
    var wrappedSocket = {

        init: function (url) {
            stompClient = Stomp.over(new SockJS(url));
        },
        connect: function (successCallback, errorCallback) {

            stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
                successCallback(frame)
            }, function (error) {
                errorCallback(error)
            });
        },
        subscribe: function (destination, callback) {
            stompClient.subscribe(destination, function (message) {
                callback(message)
            });
        },
        send: function (destination, headers, object) {
            stompClient.send(destination, headers, object);
        }
    };


    wrappedSocket.init('/ws');

    wrappedSocket.connect(
        function (frame) {
            console.info('connected', frame)
        }, function (err) {
            console.error('not connected', err)
        }
    );

    wrappedSocket.subscribe("/user/exchange/amq.direct/chat.message", function(message) {
        console.log('NEW PRIVATE MESSAGE', message)
    });

    console.log("ready!");
});
```

I can see in browser console that client is successfully connected and start subscribing given channel, but no message is received.

Can you tell how to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscription should be initialized after connection established, so try call `wrappedSocket.subscribe()` in success callback.